# События в инспекторе кода Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, opera, javascript, события

Всем привет! В Опере в инспекторе кода видно, как к определенному объекту подвешаны события. Вот скрин:

[image]

Вопрос: есть ли такая фишка в Хроме? А то найти не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CTRL + SHIFT + J`
На нужном элементе правой кнопкой клик.
Пункт `Inspect DOM property`
Там где у события будет не `null` , а `function` - там и повешено.

Comment: мдя, немного неудобно, но все равно спасибо =)